# How to find sibling of a control that raised an event in DataGrid WPF

Tags: wpf, event-handling, binding

I have a DataGrid whole columns are given below.

```
<my:DataGrid.Columns>
    <my:DataGridTemplateColumn  Header="Last Name" MinWidth="160" SortMemberPath="[LAST_NAME]">
        <my:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate >
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Name="lblLastName" Padding="5" 
                   Text="{Binding [LAST_NAME]}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </my:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </my:DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <my:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="New Age Group" IsReadOnly="True" 
                 MinWidth="130">
        <my:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ComboBox SelectedValue="{Binding AgeGroupId}" 
                      DisplayMemberPath="AgeGroupName" ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                      Name="ddlNewAgeGroup" Loaded="ddlNewAgeGroup_Loaded"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </my:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </my:DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <my:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Update" MinWidth="75" Width="100">
        <my:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Content="Update" Name="btnUpdate" Click="btnUpdate_Click"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </my:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </my:DataGridTemplateColumn>
  </my:DataGrid.Columns>
```

On btnUpdate_Click event I want to get the value that has been set on ddlNewAgeGroup

But I dont know how to find this Combobox on Button Click Event in WPF. I am using DataTables to Bind grids.

Answer (score 1):

`(e.OriginalSource as Button).DataContext` should be the object binded to your row, so it should have `AgeGroupId` property (as seen from `ComboBox.SelectedValue`), and it's a collection (as seen from ComboBox.ItemsSource). So you may find use AgeGroupName this way:

```
private void Grid_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    var row = (e.OriginalSource as Button).DataContext as %YourDataType%;
    var agegroupname = row.First(item => item.AgeGroupId == row.AgeGroupId).AgeGroupName;
    // TODO: do what you need with "agegroupname".
}
```

PS. Please set `ComboBox.SelectedValuePath` to something like `AgeGroupId`: without it, `ComboBox.SelectedValue` is equal to a whole record, not just Id